# Cascading MudListExtended or MudList will not highlite selected element

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

please advise. I need to display cascading lists in MudBlazor.

What I mean: I have two lists. The second is filled with data dependent on the selected item of the first list.

Where the problem is: if I mark an item in the first list, it populates the second list and automatically marks the first item. If I relabel the first list repeatedly, I don't run out of colabeling the first item in the second list. I don't know why.

I have prepared code that demonstrates my problem. You can run it on [trymudextensions.pages.dev](https://trymudextensions.pages.dev/).

```cs
<MudPaper>
    <MudListExtended 
        T="Item"
        ItemCollection="_items"
        Clickable="true"
        SelectedValue="_selectedItem"
        SelectedValueChanged="OnItemChanged"
        ToStringFunc="@(it => it?.Name)" />
</MudPaper>

@if (_subItems?.Count > 0)
{
    <MudPaper class="mt-4">
        <MudListExtended 
            T="SubItem"
            ItemCollection="_subItems"
            Clickable="true"
            SelectedValue="_selectedSubItem"
            SelectedValueChanged="OnSubItemChanged"
            ToStringFunc="@(it => it?.Name)" />
    </MudPaper>
}

@if (_selectedSubItem != null)
{
    <MudPaper class="mt-4">
        <MudText class="pa-3">@($"Value: {_selectedSubItem.Value}")</MudText>
    </MudPaper>
}

@code {
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Item> _items { get; set; }
    private Item _selectedItem { get; set; }

    private List<SubItem> _subItems { get; set; }
    private SubItem _selectedSubItem { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
        
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var item = new Item();
            item.Name = $"Item {i}";
            item.Items = new List<SubItem>();

            for(var j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
            {
                var subItem = new SubItem();
                subItem.Name = $"{item.Name}-{j}";
                subItem.Value = $"{(i+1)*(j+1)}";

                item.Items.Add(subItem);
            }

            _items.Add(item);
        }

        _selectedItem = _items.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void OnItemChanged(Item item)
    {
        _selectedItem = item;

        _subItems = _selectedItem.Items;
        _selectedSubItem = _subItems?.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void OnSubItemChanged(SubItem item)
    {
        _selectedSubItem = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: _If I relabel the first list repeatedly, I don't run out of colabeling the first item in the second list. I don't know why._ 
Can you explain the problem you're facing more. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try to describe my problem. If you run my code on the playground, click on "Item 1" and then "Item 2" in the first list. In the second list, the first item should always be marked (highlighted). In my case it is not.